# How to find inner center of Polygon in Python?

Tags: python, polygon

I have incoming Polygon [{x1,y1,x2,y2}] corners and want to find center of polygon for each polygon. I've googled but nothing to helps.

```
def getWallPos(x,y):

grX =  (x * y)/2
grY =  (x * y)/2
summary = grX + grY
return summary
```

I tried to do like this but it give me wrong summary. and tried to use 
**Shapely** but its give me center of each corners inner center..

Comment: Is this a math/algorithm problem? probably you should seek help from https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KevinFang not, its not, I just want to find it in Python but I dont know how

Comment: The center of a polygon is simply an average of coordinates of all the vertices. Or are you talking about something different?

Comment: @blhsing I solved it, I used shapely rightly and its work. thanks

Comment: if I may ask,I notice that shpely only has centroid mathed, the centroid is different from inner center, whitch method did you use to get the inner center?@muze